# How to display value of version column in word document?

Tags: 2013, metadata, word

I tried to include my document's version number in a word file using quick parts as described here: [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508229/how-can-i-include-value-of-sharepoints-version-column-in-a-word-document)

This doesn't work for me (SP 2013, Word 2010). It only shows {_UIVersionString} but not the actual version number.

Is there a way to do this in SP 2013?

Comment: This worked for me. The info management option was initially missing for me but enabled it in site features.
I had an issue of getting the label option available on exiting file. It took some time for it to become available. New files had the option readily available.
Thank you for the great info. But I could not find "current version" option in the insert tab as mentioned in one of the comments. Would have been handy to have that directly available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try :

Library settings -> Imformation management policies settings -> select document from content Types -> Check the checkbox to enable labels and type {version} in Label Format.

http://smackwagondesign.com/how-to-add-the-sharepoint-version-number-to-a-word-document/

Comment: That's what I tried already but it doesn't work

Comment: What other valuse have to tried in label format?

Comment: Looks like i just had to wait some time. I checked it again this morning and now it works although I didn't change anything.

Comment: great. With which string it works?

Comment: I use _{Version}_

Comment: Mark this as answer if it solves your issue

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, there is a cleaner way to do it in Sharepoint.

On Sharepoint to activate versions:

Library -> Library Settings -> Versioning settings -> Create major and minor -> OK

1. Create the document in word and upload it on Sharepoint.
2. Open the document on Sharepoint to word editor
3. Go to where the version number should be and Click on `Insert` then `Quick Parts` then `Document Properties` select `Current Version` if you have followed these steps correctly.

NB: The document should be opened from the Sharepoint uploaded version. This way you can version according to Sharepoint version number

Comment: What Office/Sharepoint version does this work with? (not with 2013, at least not here)