# SharePoint label not showing up in Word for Mac 2016

Tags: versioning, word

Im trying to get the version of a document in SharePoint (Online) to show up in Word for Mac 2016. I've tried following the instructions in the two links below:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2016-macword/how-to-display-the-versioning-number-of-a/ab808af8-5600-4ecb-9db0-2540528c96fa

[How to display value of version column in word document?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104343/how-to-display-value-of-version-column-in-word-document)

In short my document library is set up to manage versions and also under Information Management Policies it is set to include labels with the label `{Version}` which shows up as `{_UIVersionString}` in the labels section of the Information Management Policies page.

After this I have created a new document in the document library and if I look at the properties it looks as in the picture below:
[image: Label is present in SharePoint]

So it looks as if the label is present and correct in SharePoint.

Now on to my problem.

In the guides I have read you are instructed to go to "QuickParts -> Document Properties -> Label" this menu seems to be missing under Word for mac 2016 however the Fields functionality is still present and some suggested that it should be possible to insert the label by inserting a docproperty field with the label as the property. Based on this I have tried the following fields in the word document:

```
{ DOCPROPERTY "Label" \* MERGEFORMAT }  
{ DOCUMENTPROPERTY "Label" \* MERGEFORMAT }  
{ DOCUMENTPROPERTY "Version" \* MERGEFORMAT }  
{ DOCPROPERTY "Version" \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

Which gives the following result when evaluated:

> Error! Unknown document property name.
>   Error! Bookmark not defined.
>   Error! Bookmark not defined.
>   Error! Unknown document property name.

I have also tried to find ways to inspect the properties of a Word document to see if the label field is present. Microsofts support page for Word 2016 (Not mac) suggested "File -> Info -> View and edit database properties -> Document Properties" but this tab does not seem to be present in Word for Mac 2016.

Is there a way to verify that the label property has indeed been transferred from the SharePoint library to the checked out document and if so is there a way to display it in Word for Mac 2016?

And a final question: If I manage to set up a template in Word under Windows with the "Quick Parts -> Document Properties -> Label", assuming it works, is that template likely to work if checked out on a machine running OsX with Word for Mac 2016?

Any suggestions are welcome!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by setting up the label via "Quick Parts -> Document Properties -> Label" in Word under Windows.

After this it worked as intended when checking out the document in Word for Mac and it is also possible to copy the small label from one document to another (under Word for mac) and the label updates correctly and shows the SharePoint version of the document it was pasted into instantly.

It seems as if all the functionality for displaying and updating the label is there under Word for Mac but there is no way that I have found to insert the label in the document. This must be done from Word under Windows.

Please feel free to update this with possible ways of doing it from Word for mac!

Answer (score 0):

Even though Quick Parts isn't available in Word for Mac, AutoText is. It should work if you follow the guide, even if I haven't tried it myself (and not with SharePoint properties).

> ## Using AutoText on the Mac:
>
> 1. In Microsoft Word, select the text and/or graphic that you wish to
>    reuse.
> 2. Under the Insert menu on the top of the screen, click on
>    AutoText, and select New.
> 3. Give the selection a name.
> 4. Click on OK.
> 5. To
>    reuse the selection, place the cursor where you would like the text to
>    appear.
> 6. Go to Insert, AutoText, AutoText and in the box showing a list
>    of entries, highlight the name of the selection you want and then
>    click on Insert.
>
> To delete an AutoText selection, go to Insert,
> AutoText, AutoText and in the box showing a list of AutoText entries,
> highlight the name of the selection and click Delete.

Reference: [Using Quick Parts (PC) or AutoText (Mac) in Microsoft Word](https://computerservices.temple.edu/using-quick-parts-pc-or-autotext-mac-microsoft-word)

Comment: I'm afraid the AutoText functionality is not what I'm looking for since I cant get the "label/{Version}" into the document in the first place. Under the AutoText default entries I found version but this just prints the text "version" into the document. Not the version from SharePoint.


Please elaborate if I'm missing something!

Comment: @AnttiStålnacke Too bad. What happens if you add the quick part in Word 2016 (PC Version) and open the document with Mac later on?

Comment: I'm just about to set up a virtual machine to test that. Will get back to you as soon as I'm done. If anyone has a suggestion for a Mac only solution in the mean time I would be happy to explore that as well!

Comment: Doing it under windows solved the problem! To avoid forcing people to look through the comments of this answer I took the liberty of writing my own answer which immediately gives the solution. Hope this is ok and thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @AnttiStålnacke Absolutely! This is the way this system works, and my answer didn't solve the problem :-)