# place version number in word document from the document library version number

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, metadata, quick-parts

I've see [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104343/how-to-display-value-of-version-column-in-word-document) how to display version number in word but its not working for me.  The only thing i can think of that's causing the issue is that I have 2 version numbers in SharePoint document library, 1 relating to a content type i created and the other the default content type "document".

I followed the instructions for both contents types.  I created 2 documents, one from the default content type and one from the custom document type.  When I insert the quickparts to the default "document" type, it appears as a field that  you type into so doesnt reference the sharepoint version.  The other custom document type is just grey like it cant find the version number.

Any help, pointers to help resolve this one?

We're using sharepoint online.

Answer (score 1):

It will not show the actual version number when creating because the file has not already been created.

Save the file to the library. Once you open it back up from SharePoint, it should display the normal version number.

Comment: I appreciate the time taken to answer.  I've saved the file, published it and gone back in and it still doesn't show the version number within the document.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Could you please provide the screenshots of this filed in your file?